# Gradient using a color ramp only looks the way I want with a polygonal geometry. How to get this gradient spread with smooth geometry?

Tags: shaders

So logically the color ramp and and Fresnel IOR would not allow for the gradient I ended up wanting due to a low poly alternative version of an aircraft I am working on for a client. The index of refraction is set to the curvature, and thus is why the low poly looks like a unidirectional spread. I am wondering how to do it without the node setup of *Fresnel > ColorRamp > Emission Shader > Mix Shader > Material Output*.

What I don't want in terms of the gradient:

[image: What I don't want in terms of the gradient]

What I do want in terms of the gradient:

[image: what I do want in terms of the gradient]

And the node setup:

[image: and the node setup]

Comment: Hi. What's "smooth geometry" vs "polygonal geometry"? If you have the thing you do want, why isn't it good for you? What's index of refraction set to "the curvature"?

Comment: I will spoon feed. Index of refraction is the metric for which light is bent thru a medium. Think about how a straw looks out of place when looking at a cup of water at an angle. That is an example of light refraction. The polygonal geometry (low poly) of the 2nd picture is spreading the gradient how I want because of its triangulated "blocky" geometry, which affects the IOR. So then, my question is: how do you do this without the need to rely on the geometry's IOR?

Comment: I might not be bright - what do I know?.. - that's probably not for me to decide, but I am somewhat familiar with terminology in Blender, not because of my mental abilities, but simply because I use Blender professionally pretty much every workday for the last decade. I certainly did not need to be a genius to get used to it in such a long time. So, forgive me for pointing it out, but based on that experience the terms you use are a bit unusual. I think it will greatly improve your chances of getting a meaningful answer if you edit the question and form it a bit more clearly.

Comment: @TreyKing Sorry, I don't think you have to explain to him what the index of refraction is. And I'm using Blender for many years and have studied maths, but I agree with Martynas that phrases like "the index of refraction is set to the curvature" sound a bit strange. The IOR in Blender is a value which should represent the index of refraction of real world materials. So you can set it to a float value, how do you "set it to the curvature"? And all meshes objects with surfaces in Blender are polygonal. Smooth meshes are either shaded smooth or the polygons are so small they just seem smooth.

Comment: I really cannot guess what your goal here is. Maybe sharing a file might be a good idea. You can do that with https://blend-exchange.com/ I still think editing the question and formulating it in a clear manner might help, no matter how curious I am to see what happens if you leave it as it is. At the moment it isn't clear what you want to do and since the shader is not realistic, it's hard to understand what's happening in the screenshots. Might it be that the second model has its normals inverted on the right half?

Comment: Just to be clear... I did ask those questions, because I wanted to know the answers to them and more context and attempt to use that information to answer the question(except for IOR curvature one - I was mostly curious, I doubt it matters much). I don't much care about the debate regarding my mental abilities or rudeness directed at me, that's fine with me. I would still attempt to figure this out, because it looks interesting, but I really think not enough information is currently provided.